# Javascript Error but only in Firefox 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I get the following error in Firefox 4 only (not in FF 3.6.16, Safari, Chrome, Opera or IE):

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid is not a function
   loadComplete: function(){console.log('complete');} 

myfile.js line 542
```

`loadComplete` is the last line of the jqgrid block of code (which is line 542). So it reaches the end of the call to jqgrid and then throws this error.

This is on a site that has been working fine for the past year. As soon as I upgraded to Firefox 4 I ran into this. I am certain I am loading this call to jqgrid after I load all of my other javascript (and it DOES work fine in all other tested browsers and older versions of Firefox).

What could be causing something like this? I would have thought it could be solved simply by makeing sure that the call to jqgrid was made after jquery and the jqgrid plugin were loaded but... this already seems to be the case (I even tried setting a 5 second timeout on loading the bit that calls jqgrid so that everything would be certain to be loaded but it still fails). Anyway, why only in FF4?

---

**Extra info:**

Here is the order js loads on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ajaxupload.js"></script>
```

Then the specific view that loads the jqgrid calls at the end of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/viewspecific.js"></script>
```

This last is loaded by a method in the Zend Framework that can prepend, append or offset load the file. In troubleshooting this I have explicitly used append and also the offset to force this script to load dead last. I even tried just including the raw JS at the bottom of the view script, rather than loading as a separate file but nothing makes a difference.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

---

The fix, courtesy [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg), is to modify how the various included files are loaded. In the loader (jquery.jqGrid.js) you will see browser specific code like:

```
if(jQuery.browser.safari ) {
    jQuery.ajax({url:filename,dataType:'script', async:false, cache: true});
} else {
if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+filename+'"></script>');
} else {
    IncludeJavaScript(filename);
}
}
```

I replaced that with a more generic:

```
document.writeln("<script type='text/javascript' src='"+filename+"'></script>");
```

and now everything loads fine in all browsers.

Comment: What do you see via Firebug in debug mode?  Sometimes script errors aren't reported very clearly in Firefox.

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure Firefox isn't seeing any syntax errors in the jqGrid function (in the plugin source) itself (or even anywhere in the plugin source, causing it to stop being parsed before jqGrid is defined)? (Perhaps due to an odd minimization/compression problem.) Check Firebug and see if there's any errors in the plugin source. Also, maybe `jqGrid` is being added to the wrong `prototype` (seems unlikely though)?

Comment: @Pointy - Literally the only thing I see is exactly what I put in the comment, the first chunk of code formatted text about "... is not a function" That is the only thing I see.

Comment: Is that error output from Firebug? Can you construct a test case that replicates this behaviour (say, in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/))?

Comment: @Cameron - I don't see any other errors (other than the one I included in my comment) or warnings in Firebug. Sorry, just saw your jsfiddle post. I can try... there is a bunch of code to chop out to whittle this down but I will see what i can do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you use [developer version](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install#development_installation) of jqGrid. It includes many modules from which the jqGrid consist. The file `jquery.jqGrid.js` also known as `grid.loader.js` just include dynamically the modules in the specified order.

The problem is that there are many ways of dynamical including of JavaScript files and all from there has there advantages and disadvantages. If you just include in your page the `<script>` statement for all modules from `jquery.jqGrid.js` or all modules which you really need your program will work.

The same problem was before with IE. I suggested [the fix](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/jqgrid-3-7-2-bug-with-ie8-while-using-jqgrid-debugging/#p21510) to use `document.writeln` for which now included in the code of `jquery.jqGrid.js` on the [github](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/jquery.jqGrid.js), but the way will be used only for IE. It seems that Firefox 4 should also use the same way. If you use `<script>` with `jquery.jqGrid.js` inside of the `<head>` of the HTML page, than the only disadvantage of the `document.writeln` method which I know is the restriction for XHTML pages: you should not include `<xml>` header at the beginning of the page before `<!DOCTYPE ...`.

The best, simple and the most safe method like I wrote before is to include all modules which you need directly. I use personally only the way.

Comment: Oleg to the rescue. I am becoming more and more familiar with your name when it comes to jqGrid problems both here on SO and on the trirand forums. I edited the loader as you did in your IE fix and everything is working now. I will detail the specific change up in my answer but thank you very much for helping me with this.

Comment: @rg88: You are welcome! It would be good if you write the corresponding suggestion to fix the bug on the trirand forum, because the same problem will have sure many other developers.